# What is the best way to manipulate an existing PDF-Document under iOS?

Tags: ios, xcode, pdf

I need to individualize documents within an iOS-App. I could provide the origin-documents as DOCX, PDF, PPT etc. The output-format has to be PDF.

My minimun requirement is to fill some text-fields. Nice to have would be to replace an image, too.

I´m quite used to generate PDFs programmatically using `UIGraphicsBeginPDFContextToFile` etc. But in my current case I don´t want to create the whole document programmatically, I just want to replace some content.

Any hints / tipps?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DOCX is a zip - format file so you can process the contents programmatically and the reconstruct the zip file.  PPT is a binary format though newer versions of PowerPoint might also construct zip-oriented versions that you can programmatically process.  You mentioned though that you need don't want to programmatically process these documents - which I would probably also do only as a last resort.

For your DOCX origin/source documents (or doc,odt,rtf but not ppt/pdf) you could use [Docmosis](http://www.docmosis.com) cloud services if your app can have the external dependency.  You would upload your DOCX origin documents with placeholders for text-fields or images as a one-off/occasional task.  Your iOS app then calls Docmosis sending instructions and data to create the output PDF and either stream it back to the app or email/store it or both.

The upside is it takes all the load and coding away from the iOS application (there is an SDK).  The downside is it is an external depdendency.  Please note I work for the company the created Docmosis.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Interesting cloud-solution - but since I need a offline-system, no solution for me in this project. But good to know that there is a system like yours.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just load a page in a webView modal that points to a URL of a page you create? The main parts of the page would be static, and then the fields you need to customize would be populated via Javascript or PHP.

For example, we have a contact form in our app that gives you an option to view the details of your completed form after you submit. When the user clicks on the button to view the Contact Confirmation, it loads `example.com/confirmation.php` in a modal view within the iOS App.

On the `confirmation.php` page (on the web), I use PHP to pull in `$_GET` variables from the URL parameters which then populates the page with my static content, and their customized information that they entered into the form.

Comment: Interesting approach - but since I need a offline-system, no solution for me.