# iOS SDK edit PDF to add an Image

Tags: iphone, ios, pdf-generation, quartz-2d

I'm trying to figure out if there is any way to insert an image into a specific page on a pdf file. I was analying this example http://www.raywenderlich.com/6818/how-to-create-a-pdf-with-quartz-2d-in-ios-5-tutorial-part-2 and other, and they always create a new PDF file.

Is there any way to draw above the PDF page with already existing content using Quartz 2D?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

seems to be a duplicate question. Look at my question and the answers -> [What is the best way to manipulate an existing PDF-Document under iOS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13071069/what-is-the-best-way-to-manipulate-an-existing-pdf-document-under-ios)